# Problem with special characters from aspnet core to javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, alert

I am trying to pass an error message through the ModelState dictionary to be fed to a javascript code that generates an alert with that error. Everything works, but I can't get the special characters to appear correctly like " ' " and "è". Solutions?

Code AspNet Core:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Utente", "L'utente per cui si tenta di reimpostare la password non è ancora registrato");
```

Code JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey("Utente"))
    {
        @if( ViewData.ModelState["Utente"].Errors.Count > 0)
        {
          <text>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    alert('@ViewData.ModelState["Utente"].Errors.First().ErrorMessage');
                });
                </text>
        }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Html.Raw()` to prevent encoding:

```
alert("@Html.Raw(ViewData.ModelState["Utente"].Errors.First().ErrorMessage)");
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: I saw that you changed your answer and I didn't notice. Now works! Thank you!

Comment: @Elmoro: Glad it helps :)

Comment: This works for me:

alert("@Html.Raw(ViewData.ModelState["Utente"].Errors.First().ErrorMessage)");

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quote instead of single quote in message variable

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var message = "@Html.Raw(ViewData.ModelState["Utente"].Errors.First().ErrorMessage)";
   alert(message);
});
```

Comment: Nothing to do :(